# Android accessibility restrict talkback to reading only the visible text

Tags: android, textview, accessibility, ellipsis, talkback

I have a `TextView` with `maxLines="1"` and a long string of text set to it.
`ellipsize="end"` truncates the text after 1 line, but the talkback, goes on the read the entire text which is not visible in the `TextView`.

```
                   <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_title"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:text="@{titleText}" />
```

Can I restrict the talkback to reading only the text that is visible in the `TextView` rather than reading the entire text?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`android:contentDescription`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:contentDescription) to override what Talkback announces for the TextView.  You can't really determine how much text is visible before the ellipses because the user might set the fontsize to be bigger in their accessibility settings, causing less text to be displayed before the ellipses, but if you know the text you want to read, you can set it in `contentDescription`.

I would be cautious about doing this, though.  The `ellipsize` is mainly a visual feature to let the user know there's more text to display than can fit on the screen.  If the screen were bigger (or the text shorter), then all of it would be displayed.  Screen reader users don't really care if the text can fit on the screen or not and will typically want to hear the entire text.

Comment: Thanks @slugolicious. I am aware of the contentDescription method. Although, I was hoping if there was some standard way of implementing this. But looks like there aren't many options around handling ellipsized text with talkback.

Comment: I wanted to state the obvious answer first :-). Your OP didn’t say you had tried `contentDescription`.